# Replacing a node in a frozen Tensorflow model

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, deep-learning, data-science

I have a `frozen inference graph` stored in a `.pb file`, which was obtained from a `trained Tensorflow model` by the `freeze_graph` function.

**Suppose, for simplicity,** that I would like to change some of the `sigmoid activations` in the model to `tanh activations` (and let's not discuss whether this is a good idea).

**How can this be done with access only to the frozen graph in the .pb file, and without the possibility to retrain the model?**

I am aware of the `Graph Editor library in tf.contrib`, which should be able to do this kind of job, but I wasn't able to figure out a simple way to do this in the documentation.

Answer (score 2):

The solution is to use `import_graph_def`:

```
import tensorflow as tf
sess = tf.Session()

def load_graph(frozen_graph_filename):
    with tf.gfile.GFile(frozen_graph_filename, "rb") as f:
        graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
        graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read())
    with tf.Graph().as_default() as graph:
        tf.import_graph_def(graph_def, name='')
    return graph
graph_model = load_graph("frozen_inference_graph.pb")
graph_model_def = graph_model.as_graph_def()

graph_new = tf.Graph()
graph_new.as_default()
my_new_tensor = # whatever
tf.import_graph_def(graph_model_def, name='', input_map={"tensor_to_replace": my_new_tensor})
#do somthing with your new graph
```

[Here](http://digital-thinking.de/tensorflow-replace-tensors-of-a-savedmodel-or-frozengraph/) I wrote a post about it

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this:

`graph = load_graph(filename)`
`graph_def = graph.as_graph_def()`
`# if ReLu op is at node 161`
`graph_def.node[161].op="tanh"`
`tf.train.write_graph(graph_def, path2savfrozn, "altered_frozen.pb", False)`

Please let know the if it works.

Answer (score 0):

The *.pb file contains a SavedModel protocol buffer. You should be able to load it using a [SavedModel loader](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/saved_model/loader). You can also inpsect it with the [SavedModel CLI](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/saved_model#cli_to_inspect_and_execute_savedmodel). The full documentation on SavedModels is [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/saved_model#apis_to_build_and_load_a_savedmodel).

Comment: My main question is how to replace e.g. the `sigmoid` activations with `tanh` activations in the existing graph. As for loading the model, I am using the `tf.import_graph_def` function, which works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Something along these lines should work:

```
graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
with open('frozen_inference.pb', 'rb') as f:
    graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read())

with tf.Graph().as_default() as graph:
    importer.import_graph_def(graph_def, name='')

new_model = tf.GraphDef()

with tf.Session(graph=graph) as sess:

    for n in sess.graph_def.node:

        if n.op == 'Sigmoid':
            nn = new_model.node.add()
            nn.op = 'Tanh'
            nn.name = n.name
            for i in n.input:
                nn.input.extend([i])

        else:
            nn = new_model.node.add()
            nn.CopyFrom(n)
```