# Tensorflow: modifying node operation using a frozen graph (graph edit)

Tags: tensorflow, graph, edit, operation

I would like to modify/change operations using a frozen graph.
For example, as below, modify ops from "upsample2D whose resizing method is ResizeNearestNeighbor" to 'upsample2D whose resizing method is ResizeBilinear"

```
with tf.device('/gpu:0'):
    with tf.gfile.GFile(filename, 'rb') as file:
        serialized_graph = file.read()
        graph_def.ParseFromString(serialized_graph)
        tf.import_graph_def(graph_def, name='')
        graph_replace = tf.contrib.graph_editor.graph_replace
        nodes = graph_def.node
        for node in nodes:
            if "ResizeNearestNeighbor" in node.name :
                print ("===========> ", node.name)
                node.op ="ResizeBilinear"
                # also need to change node name                   
        nodes = graph_def.node
        for node in nodes:
            print (node.name)
        tf.train.write_graph(graph_def, "./", name='modified.pb')
```

Actually, the above code is not working; I think it's due to unhashable type in nodedef; also, decoding error google.protobuf.message.DecodeError: Error parsing message when importing modified graph

I think the following methods may work, but any help for this?

```
graph_replace = tf.contrib.graph_editor.graph_replace
graph_replace(node, {node.xx: new_node.xx })
```

or,

```
tf.import_graph_def(graph_def, input_map={node: a new node})
```

Thanks

Comment: Seemingly, tf.train.write_graph(graph_def, "./", name='modified.pb') is working, but the pb fails to be parsed and the file size is much larger than original size.

Comment: Take a look at this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47379766/replacing-a-node-in-a-frozen-tensorflow-model/53077609#53077609

Answer (score 1):

Your main code block is somewhat strange:

- You create `graph_replace` but never use it.
- You match on `node.name`. Names can be pretty much anything. You should probably match on `node.op`, which is the "type" of the operation. These names are fixed.
- You change the the nodes type in `node.op ="ResizeBilinear"`. This does not sound right. It is analogous to `char a; boom = (uint64) a` in C. You can't just change the "type" of something.

In general, modifying the GraphDef by hand is a bad idea. It is not part of the public interface and can change at any time.

Using `graph_editor` is probably the best approach. You can use the graph `Transformer` and override the `transform_op_handler`. See this [test](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/23c218785eac5bfe737eec4f8081fd0ef8e0684d/tensorflow/contrib/graph_editor/tests/transform_test.py#L85) for basic example of using Transformer. You can base your handler on the default [one](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/16a965c5c9a64ef82ccfcb849dd61e6aad00d10e/tensorflow/contrib/graph_editor/transform.py#L132) that just copies the node as is. In case it helps, here is the [place](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/16a965c5c9a64ef82ccfcb849dd61e6aad00d10e/tensorflow/contrib/graph_editor/transform.py#L467) where this transformer is used.

Answer (score 0):

I have just faced a similar problem and found a solution. I don't know if it's possible just to rename the operation, so I guess you need to completly exchange the node.

To solve that, you need to define a new Operation like this:

```
output_tensor= tf.image.resize_images(input_tensor, [300, 300], method=tf.image.ResizeMethod.BILINEAR)
```

and then use

```
tf.import_graph_def(graph_model_def, name='', input_map={"existing_input_tensor": input_tensor}, return_elements=['data/inputs:0'])
```

[Here](http://digital-thinking.de/tensorflow-replace-tensors-of-a-savedmodel-or-frozengraph/) is a more detailed explanation.