# How to remove the last layer from Hub Module in Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-hub

I want to remove the last layer(s) from [MobileBERT](https://tfhub.dev/google/mobilebert/uncased_L-24_H-128_B-512_A-4_F-4_OPT/1) from Hub. I know there is a solution for [Keras Model in TensorFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55392591/how-to-remove-the-last-layer-from-trained-model-in-tensorflow), but this case is different from that one.

I was thinking of something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47379766/replacing-a-node-in-a-frozen-tensorflow-model), but it doesn't seem user-friendly.

What is the common way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

There is no first-class APIs to do this. The solution along the lines what [you have mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63056511/how-to-remove-the-last-layer-from-hub-module-in-tensorflow) is the way to go.